# New Mapquest tile server URL

Tags: leaflet, mapquest

I have created a map using classic MapQuest tiles. I have got tile server URL from here: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

I noticed that changes I have made in Open Street Map editor are not showing in classic MapQuest. So I think they don't update the old version of MapQuest anymore.

Maybe I can move my map on the new MapQuest tiles, but I can't find tile server URL. Is there any possibility to use new MapQuest tiles?

Comment: As you figured out, MapQuest seems to [phase out](https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/mapquest-osm-tiles) its open tiles service. If you want up-to-date tiles, you probably have to subscribe to one of their commercial plans (starts for free but with limitations on usage).

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct access to tiles any more. There is a Leaflet [plugin](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins) provided to display MapQuest tiles in a Leaflet map along with geocode, route, and traffic plugins too.