# How can I use MapQuest tiles with leaflet directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet, openstreetmap, mapquest

I have the following code to use open street tiles to display a map

```
angular.extend($scope, {
                center: {
                    lat: myLat,
                    lng: myLon,
                    zoom: 3
                },

                events: {
                    markers: {
                        enable: ['dragend']
                    }
                },
                layers: {
                    baselayers: {
                        osm: {
                            name: 'OpenStreetMap',
                            url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                            type: 'xyz'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can I change it to use MapQuest tiles?

Cheers

Comment: See the URL provided on that page: http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/ But as pointed out on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871225/new-mapquest-tile-server-url/), there is no guarantee about how long the tiles will still be available.

Comment: What is a good free option?

Comment: Define "free". Hosting tiles costs money. All tile providers will have certain limits and usage policies.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're willing to pay for Mapquest's tileservice (thnx @ghybs :)) I'de advise against using Mapquest tiles because they're phasing out their tile providing service. As you can see on their own map application, they've started to use Mapbox tiles, check the attribution in the lower right corner: http://www.mapquest.com/

Comment: Actually OP did not explicitly said that he was not willing to subscribe to MapQuest commercial plans… :-) But you are absolutely right about the MapQuest Open Tiles being phased out. See [MQBrian's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871225/new-mapquest-tile-server-url/34724382#34724382). I wonder if it is the same MQBrian as [there](https://developer.mapquest.com/forum/mapquest-osm-tiles).

Comment: Wasn't even aware of their commercial plans :D Thanks for the heads up, i'll amend